# Linq To Sql Transaction Error

Tags: linq-to-sql, transactions

I'm getting the following error:
Method 'Boolean CheckPermmision(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL

From The function

```
return (from Ct in db.Salers
                    where Ct.isActive == true && Ct.Profile.MCID == GetActivatorMCID()
                           && CheckPermmision(GetUid(),Ct.EventID,10,Ct.Premission_Level,0)
                    select Ct).ToList();
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call non-sql methods in a linq-to-sql query. The methods you are calling have to be mapable to sql commands.